# Best way to create modular SVG animations

Tags: javascript, svg

I want to create an animation which results from the movement of several "components". At the moment I handcoded SVG tags, but aim at generate them; this is how one of my component appears and my code:

```
<g style="transform-origin:39%;transform: rotate(180deg);">
   <circle id="pippo" cx="0" cy="0" r="5" fill="#333333">
       <animateMotion dur="0.7s" repeatCount="once" fill="freeze"
calcMode="spline" keyTimes="0;1" keySplines="0.27 0 0 1">
           <mpath xlink:href="#shorterPath"/>
       </animateMotion>
   </circle>
</g>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/fillotassi/by3Lxf0h/19/

Which is a good way to create instances of an svg with custom properties through javascript?

Comment: Do you want to use vanilla javascript?

Comment: Yes. Would you suggest to do otherwise?

Comment: AFAIK [animateTransform](https://www.w3.org/TR/2011/REC-SVG11-20110816/animate.html#AnimateTransformElement) and [animateMotion](https://www.w3.org/TR/smil-animation/) require browser support for the [SMIL animation standard](https://www.w3.org/TR/smil-animation/). Microsoft don't support it and running the fiddle HTML code doesn't animate in Edge. The alternative is to redesign using CSS animations - instead of dynamically creating SVG animations you dynamically create CSS rules as well. Which do you want to pursue - SMIL or CSS?

Comment: Thanks. I don't know clearly the limitations of both; I'd stick with SMIL as it looks more powerful

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Creating dynamic SVG elements and animations in JavaScript.

#### Namespaces

SVG elements must be created using the `document.createElementNS` method and explicitly providing the SVG namespace URI "http://www.w3.org/2000/svg".

Attribute values of an svg element can generally be added using the element's `setAttribute` or `setAttributeNS` method.

Attribute names prefixed with `xlink:` don't work properly if added using `setAttribute` - use `setAttributeNS` with the xlink namespace URI "http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" instead.

Note that use of the `xlink:` prefix for `href` attributes has been [deprecated in SVG2](https://svgwg.org/svg2-draft/linking.html#XLinkRefAttrs) in favor of the name "href" without a prefix.

See also: [Namespaces Crash Course](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Namespaces_Crash_Course) on MDN

#### Properties

Attempting to set attribute values by setting them as property names of svg elements can lead to failure when the *property* is  read only. SVG properties with the same name as attributes may have a getter (without a setter) and return an object implementing the [SVG animated length](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/SVGAnimatedLength#SVG_animated_length_interface) or 
[SVGAnimated​String](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/SVGAnimatedString) interface.

For example,

- `svgElement.className` may be read only - preferably use `setAttribute("class", value)` or `element.classList.add(name, value)` instead. See [className notes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/className#Notes).
- `circleShape.r` is read only (as are other property names for animatable attributes of other elements). See [SVGCircleElement properties](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/SVGCircleElement#Properties).

#### Example

Note the `createSvgElement` helper function uses a `for ... in` loop and was not written to handle random enumerable properties added to `Object.prototype`. The code for `xlink:` prefixed attribute names was tested  but not used here.

```js
"use strict";
function createSvgElement( tagName, attributes) {
    var element = document.createElementNS(
        "http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", tagName);
    if( attributes) {
        for( var attr in attributes) {
            if( /^xlink:/.test( attr)) {
                element.setAttributeNS( "http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink",
                    attr, attributes[ attr]);
            }
            else { 
                element.setAttribute( attr, attributes[ attr]);
            }
        }
    }
    return element;
}

let svg = createSvgElement("svg", {
    width: "200",
    height: "200",
    viewBox: "0 0 200 200",
    style: "background:aquamarine",

});
let defs = createSvgElement("defs");
defs.appendChild(createSvgElement( "path", {
    id: "verticalMotionPath",
    d: "m 100,100 0, 50"
}));
defs.appendChild( createSvgElement( "path", {
    id: "shorterPath",
    d: "m 100,70 0, 50"
}));
svg.appendChild( defs);

function circleGroup( originTx, rotateDegrees, pathId, circleId) {
    let group = createSvgElement("g");
    group.style =
      "transform-origin: "+originTx
       +"; transform: rotate("+ rotateDegrees + "deg);";
    let circle = createSvgElement("circle", { r: 5, fill: "#333333"});
    let am = createSvgElement("animateMotion", {
        dur:"0.7s",
        repeatCount: 1,
        fill: "freeze",
        calcMode: "spline",
        keyTimes: "0;1",
        keySplines: "0.27 0 0 1"
    });
    am.appendChild( createSvgElement("mpath", {
        "href": "#" + pathId
    }));
    circle.appendChild( am);
    group.appendChild(circle);
    return group;
}
// draw animations and append svg to body
[180, 0, 60, -60].forEach( function( angle) {
    svg.appendChild( circleGroup("50%", angle, "verticalMotionPath"));
});
["61%", "39%"].forEach( function( originTx) {
    svg.appendChild( circleGroup(originTx, 180, "shorterPath"));
});
document.body.appendChild( svg);
```

#### Discussion (aside)

The example demonstrates how one might write a function, `circleGroup`, to implement the animation shown in the post and call it multiple times for repeated effects. It is not *exactly* the same as the fiddle because of choices for what and how to pass arguments to `circleGroup` and some  simplifications. These could be modified in a final application - or the function rewritten entirely :-)

Testing early and in multiple browsers can help. For example to get something (anything !) working, I went back to making one change to working source code - which was to remove the `mpath` element of the first group and create it in JavaScript. I incorrectly used `setAttribute` for the `xlink:href` attribute and it didn't work. Logging the created element and drilling down in one browser stopped at listing the mpath element's outer HTML which, unfortunately, was the same as an element created in source. Another browser allowed me to drill further down to discover internal property value were not set the same as for an `mpath` element originating in source code.

#### Browser Support

SVG animation using `animateMotion`, `animateTransform` or the deprecated `animateColor` elements are based on the [SMIL animation W3C standard](http://www.w3.org/TR/smil-animation). SMIL is not supported by Microsoft browsers, and Microsoft have previously stated that support is not under consideration. The example does not work in Edge at the time of writing.

Comment: Didn't read it all, but "Many attributes values of svg elements **must** be added using either the setAttribute or setAttributeNS", nope, most (if not all) SVG attributes have their corresponding IDL attribute. For instance className exists. The thing is that many of these are animatable, so you need to set their `baseVal`, e.g `svgElement.className.baseVal = "foo"`, but for this particularly bad example you would even be better using `Element.prototype.classList`, which would behave the same on HTMLElements and SVGElements.

Comment: @Kaiido thank you greatly for the feedback, if coalesced many behaviors I had seen.  I've seriously revised the answer in response.

Comment: If you want to Microsoft browsers to do SMIL you can use [fakeSmile](https://github.com/FakeSmile/FakeSmile) to do that.